# Is there a link between an object named "a" and an object named "_a"?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS so take me slow. When i declare an object in my .h view controller named "_a" and i declare a property "a" and when i synthesize in the .m file

```
@synthesize a=_a;
```

must i use "a" or "_a" when i modify that object ? ( "a" is a UINavigationController in my case).

In another question, does my compiler automatically draw a connection from a object declared "ob" to a "_ob" declaration ?

Again, sorry for the poor explanation but this environment isn't quite something i am use to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object declared like this:

```
@interface Example : NSObject {
    NSObject *_a;
}
@property (retain) NSObject *a;
@end
```

And implemented like this:

```
#import "Example.h"

@implementation Example
@synthesize a = _a;
@end
```

Makes an ivar named `_a` and two accessor methods in the `Example` object. The accessor methods have these signatures:

```
- (NSObject *)a;
- (void)setA:(NSObject *)theA;
```

Method `a` returns the object in the `_a` ivar. Method `setA` releases the object stored in `_a` (if not nil), assigns the parameter to `_a`, and sends the parameter an `retain` message.

These methods may also be access through dot notation:

```
Example *e = [[Example alloc] init];
// These two are equivalent. 
e.a = anotherNSObject;
[e setA:anotherNSObject];
// These two are equivalent.
anotherNSObject = e.a;
anotherNSObject = [e a];
```

Accessing `_a` directly will circumvent the accessor methods, potentially causing problems such as memory leaks. For example if `_a` holds the only reference to an object and a new object reference is assigned to `_a` the old object will become a leaked object.

To directly answer your two questions:

You may use either `a` or `_a`. In most cases you'll be better off using `_a` when reading the value within methods of the object declaring `a`, and `setA` (or `a` in dot notation) when setting the value of `_a`. Objects that use `Example` objects should use the accessor methods (with or without dot notation).

The complier does not automatically make a connection between `ob` and `_ob` declarations. In this example the `@synthesize a = _a;` statement makes the connection with the optional `= _a`. The ivar may have any name. `@synthesize a = george;` would also be valid. Without the `= _a` part the compiler would make an ivar named `a` and two accessor methods.

One further note: You may omit the declaration of `_a` in the interface, which restricts the scope of the `_a` ivar to just the implementation of the Example object. Adding the optional `= _a` to the `@synthesize` statement will make as ivar of the same type as the property declared in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

@synthesize tell to compiler to generate setter and getter methods for your property. You can use _a as ivar or self.a as property, there are no difference.
Also you can set your class variable from another class via this property

```
[myClassInstance setA:newA];
oldA = [myClassInstance a]; //oldA = myClassInstance.a
```

Comment: _"You can use _a as ivar or self.a as property, there are no difference"_ — That's not true. There is a difference. For example, if your property is marked retain, then doing `self.a = object;` will correctly release the old and retain the new, but doing `_a = object;` will leak the old object and fail to retain the new one, causing crashes unless you've handled it yourself. Likewise, if you've written any custom getters/setters, they won't be called if you access the instance variable (`_a`) directly, instead of using the property.

Comment: You are right about overriden properties, where i can write in getter for example `return nil; // or 0`. In this case will difference between ivar and property for this ivar.

Comment: Regarding your example with retain, it's inappropriate, because you don't know how property marked (assign, retain). Also `_a = object` NOT will leak, this is simply assigning pointer.

Comment: You're still wrong. _"Also _a = object NOT will leak, this is simply assigning pointer"_ It'll leak if there was anything already in `_a` that had been retained, unless you manually call release on it first. "Simply assigning pointers" is the most common cause of memory leaks! Yes, I don't know how the property is marked — if it's marked `nonatomic, assign`, and you can guarantee that it will always be marked thus, and that you'll never change which instance variable it backs onto, never write a custom accessor, etc, then they're equivalent… but that assumption removes future flexibility.